# How to filter a pivot table based on year and month?

Tags: excel, vba

When filtering a pivot table using VBA, I have an error

> '424' object required"

When new records for 2022 were added in my Excel file my code stopped working.

It works when getting to 12 (December) but instead of proceeding I get error '424'.

I'm trying to filter a pivot table based on year and month.

Here's the part of the code that doesn't work.

```vb
Dim pivotyear       As String
Dim myPivotField    As PivotField
Dim PT              As PivotTable
Dim dday            As Integer
Dim grantotal       As Integer

wbk1.Activate
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("year")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each PivotItem In .PivotItems
        If PivotItem = "2021" Then PivotItem.Visible = TRUE
        If PivotItem <> "2021" Then PivotItem.Visible = FALSE
    Next
End With

mmonth = Month(Range("a1").Value)

If mmonth = "" Then Exit Sub

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("month")
    .ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    For PivotItem = 1 To mmonth
        
        If PivotItem = mmonth Then PivotItem.Visible = TRUE
        If PivotItem <> mmonth Then PivotItem.Visible = FALSE
    Next
End With
```

Comment: You're trying to use `pivotitem` as a number and an object. It can't be both at once.

Comment: Thank you for your resonse !!!It filters my pivot until 12 (december ) and then i get this error

Comment: @BigBen at  line --> If PivotItem = mmonth Then PivotItem.Visible = True when mmonth =12  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Your last 4 lines can't possibly work, since Pivotitem is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Set the month filter in the same way as the year.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
      
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, item As pivotitem
    Dim pyear As String, pmonth As String
        
    Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    wbk1.Activate
        
    If Not IsDate(Range("A1")) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date '" & Range("A1") & "' in [A1]", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    pmonth = Format(Range("A1"), "m")
    pyear = Format(Range("A1"), "yyyy")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        With .PivotFields("year")
            .ClearAllFilters
            For Each item In .PivotItems
                If item.Value <> pyear Then item.Visible = False
            Next
        End With
        
        With .PivotFields("month")
            .ClearAllFilters
            For Each item In .PivotItems
                If item.Value <> pmonth Then item.Visible = False
            Next
        End With
        .PivotCache.Refresh
     End With    
End Sub
```